# List all stored procedures with schema name

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, database-schema

Can anyone advise on a way to list all stored procedures along with their schema names in a database? Thanks!

Comment: try `select * from DatabaseName.information_schema.routines where routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'`

Comment: Thanks, aserwin and marc_s. How do I know this will list ALL stored procedures for this database b/c I ran this and got 164 rows, compared to 1,510 records when I ran another query, which I didn't save, so I'm not sure what it was :-(.

Answer (score 37):

```
SELECT [schema] = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]),
  name
FROM sys.procedures;
```

or

```
SELECT [schema] = SCHEMA_NAME([schema_id]),
  name
FROM sys.procedures;
```

For a specific database, you can just change the context to that database first, or change Marc's query slightly (my queries are no good in this case because they rely on functions that are context-sensitive):

```
SELECT 
    SchemaName = s.name,
    ProcedureName = pr.name 
FROM 
    databasename.sys.procedures pr
INNER JOIN 
    databasename.sys.schemas s ON pr.schema_id = s.schema_id;
```

If you want to do this for all databases:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'
  UNION ALL SELECT db = N''' + name + ''', 
    s.name COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI,
    o.name COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
  FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.procedures AS o
  INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.schemas AS s
  ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]'
FROM sys.databases
-- WHERE ... -- probably don't need system databases at least

SELECT @sql = STUFF(@sql, 1, 18, '') 
  -- you may have to adjust  ^^ 18 due to copy/paste, cr/lf, tabs etc 
  + ' ORDER BY by db, s.name, o.name';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

The collate clauses are necessary in case you have databases with different collations.

Comment: For SQL 2014 you can just skip `databasename` and use `use databasename`.

Comment: @MichałWoliński That doesn't work if you need to union a query across multiple databases (you can't say `USE` in the middle of a query). A database prefix on an object name does have a purpose.

Comment: I know, but question was for procedures in database, not multiple databases. Without database prefix 1st snippet will be easier to use. For multiple databases there is 2nd snippet, isn't it?

Comment: @MichałWoliński If you're just talking about the procedures in the database you're already in, it doesn't really matter; neither `USE` nor a database prefix are necessary.

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    SchemaName = s.name,
    ProcedureName = pr.name 
FROM 
    sys.procedures pr
INNER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON pr.schema_id = s.schema_id
```

This should list all stored procedures and their schema name as a result set.

Both views - `sys.procedures` and `sys.schemas` - have quite a few more attributes - check them out, if you need them, include them in your query.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. How would I use this to list all stored procedures and their schemas for a specific database?

Comment: @daniness: go to that database (`use (yourdatabase)`) and then execute this snippet of code. It works only against the database you're currently in.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to search for procs with required schema name you can use this query:

```
SELECT 
    SchemaName = s.name,
    ProcedureName = pr.name 
FROM 
    sys.procedures pr
INNER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s 
ON pr.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE s.name = 'YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME'
ORDER BY SchemaName;
```

Answer (score 1):

this may help You..

> SELECT * FROM sys.procedures;

Comment: It will not return all procedures.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Script Generator to get them. In the left pan right click on the database for which you want to get Stored Procedures, Tasks->Generate Scripts Click Next and choose Select Specific Database Objects and select Stored Procedures and click on next, there you can customize as you need and generate the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
execute [sys].[sp_stored_procedures]
```

Or try this and also get all parameters:

```
execute [sys].[sp_sproc_columns]
```

Ok...you'll have to loop through all DB catalog names with this, but...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name,crdate  FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE (type = 'P')  order by name 

SELECT [schema] = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]),name FROM sys.procedures;

select OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]) as 'SchemaName',name as 'SP Name ' ,

create_date,modify_date FROM sys.procedures order by OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]), name
```

Comment: Add some description to it, why it will work and how it works.